# How to determine the slope for the gravity flow of highly viscous fluids (eg. gum)?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pipelines, viscosity

I am looking for a method to determine the slope of the pipe required to maintain a gravity flow for highly viscous fluid.

The Hazen-Williams equation for gravity flow is applicable for liquids which have viscosity nearly equal to water. Can we use it in our case?

Comment: Have you considered using Darcy Weißbach with Bernoulli's equation ? What  is the size is the pipework? What is the fluid? What is the height difference you are looking at ?

Comment: Gum sticks to the underside of desks and rarely moves so what movement do you expect?